# Unable to sort multilist in python

Tags: python

I tried to sort list within a list but failed to do so , Is something wrong with my code ?

```
x = [[int(i)] for i in raw_input().split()]
print x

q = x.sort(key=lambda p: p[0])
print q
```

Before this I tried simpler code such as:

```
x = [[int(i)] for i in raw_input().split()]
print (x.sort())
```

But the result is same in both cases :

[image]

Comment: `x.sort` modifies in place, it does not return the sorted list.

Comment: As @LutzHorn mentions... it's in place... so you want to `print(x)` again - not `q`. Also - do you really want a list of lists there? Looks like a simple list of `int`s would be fine.

Comment: `x.sort()` does not return a value. Dont do this `q = x.sort(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.sort` is an in-place operation that returns `None`. So you're assigning `None`.

If you want a **new** list to be returned as a value use `sorted`:

```
q = sorted(x, key=...)
print(q)
```

If you want to mutate the `x` in place use:

```
x.sort(...)
print(x)
```

Tip - to get a flat list use:

```
from itertools import chain

q = list(chain.from_iterable(x))
```

And now if you want to sort:

```
q = sorted(q) # no need for key
```